# Differences between Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS and Power BI?

Tags: statistics, arcgis-platform, diagram, operations-dashboard, power-bi

We are looking for a possibilty to show some live statistics and calculation over geodata (the developement on some retail markets ) and want to see what is suitable. I have tried Power BI and have seen there is a possibilty to show maps and statistics at the same time.

I have read About Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS too but unfortunately do not have direct access to that to be able to test it.

Can you guide me about the necessity of Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS and its advantages in comparison to Power BI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good start would be to check out [Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/operations-dashboard/)

It would be a good addition if you are looking to add to your tool set as you can:

> Use charts, gauges, maps, and other visual elements to reflect the status and performance of people, services, assets, and events in real time. From a dynamic dashboard, view the activities and key performance indicators most vital to meeting objectives.

One item to note, Power BI needs network connectivity and you don't have the ability view maps offline [ArcGIS maps in Power BI service and Power BI Desktop by Esri](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-arcgis)

The advantage here is if you can make a good map with many functionalities that is were the real effectiveness of Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS comes into play. Here are some recommendations offered [Create web maps for dashboards](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/operations-dashboard/help/create-web-maps-for-dashboards.htm)

- Setting refresh levels
- Switching Operational layer visibility
- Styling of data

Here are some examples [Some Example Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS Apps & Resources](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/apps/decision-support/some-example-operations-dashboard-for-arcgis-apps-resources/)

[FAQs](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/operations-dashboard/faqs/faqs.htm#anchor3)

> Can I embed another app within my dashboard? Yes. Use the embedded content element to do this.